# XSLT 2.0, Xpath, DITA: Select all content between two elements of same name

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, dita

I'm taking a flat HTML source and converting it to hierarchical DITA file*s*, with their associated `.ditamap`.

<s>It's [fiddled](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YH), but of course, `<result-document>` won't work there.</s>

edit: It's [refiddled](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5M) to a smaller more concise reflection of the problem.

I'm close. This represents my source. It looks complex, but isn't: the result documents will be everything between `<concept>` elements .. regardless of the nesting/complexity therein.

```
<!--
     this is an interim file while converting flat html
     to a hierarchical DITA structure
  -->
  <concepts text-title="Manual" id="manual">
     <concept id="chapter1">
        <title>Chapter 1</title>
        <conbody>
           <p>contents in body will</p>
           <lq><i>vary</i> widely</lq>
           <concept id="subchapter1-1">
              <title>Subchapter 1</title>
              <conbody>
                 <table>table</table>
                 <lq>foo</lq>
              </conbody>            
           </concept>
        </conbody>
     </concept>
     <concept id="chapter2">
        <title>Chapter 2</title>
        <conbody>
           <table>table</table>
           <lq>foo <pre>code</pre></lq>
        </conbody>
        <concept id="subchapter2-1">
           <title>Subchapter 1</title>
           <conbody>
              <table>table</table>
              <lq><b>foo</b></lq>
           </conbody>            
        </concept>            
     </concept>         
  </concepts>
```

This my xslt, I made comments in the area where my difficulty is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
xmlns:mf="http://example.org/mf"                
version="2.0">

<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    doctype-system="../dtd/technicalContent/dtd/map.dtd" 
    doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes"/>    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!--
    Source: monolithic XML file containing many nested <concept> topics
    Transform outcomes:
        1. Transform of source will create a DITA <map><topicref>
        2. A <result-document> will write out each <concept> as a singular file       
-->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <map 
        title="{/concepts/@text-title}"
        id="{/concepts/@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="concepts">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="concept">

    <xsl:variable name="path-filename" select="concat('/home/mike/dita/prodrun/',@id,'.dita')"/>
    <!-- transform source to make the DITA <map> -->
    <topicref href="{$path-filename}" type="concept">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </topicref>

    <!-- write out this <concept> to the file system -->
    <xsl:result-document
        method="xml"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="no"
        indent="yes"
        doctype-system="../../dtd/technicalContent/dtd/concept.dtd" 
        doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN"            
        href="{$path-filename}">
        <concept id="new foo will be added here">
            <!-- 
                Below is one of my efforts. I need to select ALL, to stopping short of next <concept>
                I also tried <for-each-group's .. to no avail
            -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[not(self::*)][preceding::concept[1]]"/>    
        </concept>
    </xsl:result-document>

</xsl:template>
```

At the end, I'll have the `ditamap`, that part works. I'll also have four files like this in my file system:

```
 <concept id="t20">
     <title>Chapter 1</title>
     <conbody>
        <p>contents in body will</p>
        <lq><i>vary</i> widely</lq>
     </conbody>
  </concept>

  <concept id="subchapter1-1">
     <title>Subchapter 1</title>
     <conbody>
        <table>table</table>
        <lq>foo</lq>
     </conbody>            
  </concept>

  <concept id="chapter2">
     <title>Chapter 2</title>
     <conbody>
        <table>table</table>
        <lq>foo <pre>code</pre></lq>
     </conbody>
  </concept>

  <concept id="subchapter2-1">
     <title>Subchapter 1</title>
     <conbody>
        <table>table</table>
        <lq><b>foo</b></lq>
     </conbody>            
  </concept>
```

**FWIW**: I'm working in OxygenXML, but I will run this routinely with Saxon from the command line.

**Sidenote**: this really opened my eyes up to the utility of doctypes, namespaces and validating on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, have to do work instead of this ;)

```
<!--concept id="new foo will be added here"-->
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
            <title>
                <xsl:copy-of select="title/@*|title/node()"/>    
            </title>
            <conbody>
                <xsl:copy-of select="conbody/@*|conbody/node()"/>    
            </conbody>
            <!-- 
            Below is one of my efforts. I need to select ALL, to stopping short of next <concept>
            I also tried <for-each-group's .. to no avail
        -->

            <!--xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[not(self::*)][preceding::concept[1]]"/-->    
        </concept>
```

Comment: Tried it. It overshot.  (ie. It pulled Subchapter 1 into Chapter 1).

Comment: How about now? Note, that your chapter1 is not following DITA DTD (it has concept inside conbody), but according to my tests this should be working now... I hope.

Answer (score 0):

What I have so far (simplified source for demo, [fiddled](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifoZ)). It seems to work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes"/>    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">    
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="concept"/>

<!-- 
    The xpath in the <for-each> below:
    ..give me the descendants of this <concept>..
    ..excluding descendants that may be in 
    descendant 'nested' <concept>'s
-->

<xsl:template match="concepts">
    <documents>
        <xsl:for-each select="//concept">
            <simulated-result-document>
                <xsl:for-each 
                    select="node() | text()
                    [descendant::*]                    
                    [not(descendant::concept[self::concept])]"> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </simulated-result-document>        
        </xsl:for-each>
    </documents>
</xsl:template>
```

Source XML:

```
   <concepts>
  <concept id="1">
     <title>Title 1 - General</title>
     Test unbound text here. 
     <p>In determining the..</p>
     <p>Words describing the singular..</p>
     <p>Words describing the plural..</p>      
     <concept id="2">
        <title>Chapter 2 - Rules</title>
        <p>Words implying the masculine gender..</p>
        <p>Words implying the feminine..</p>
        <p>words in the present tense..</p>
        <concept id="3">
           <title>§ 1. Gender</title>
           <p>Male.. text text text </p>
           <p>Female.. text text text </p>            
        </concept>
        <concept id="4">
           <title>§ 2. Jurisdiction</title>
           <p>Time.. jurisdiction text text text</p>
           <p>Place.. jurisdiction text text text</p>
           <p>Person.. jurisdiction text text text</p>
           <concept id="4.1">
              <title>§ 2.1 Status</title>
              <p>Citizen.. text text text </p>
              <p>Stateless.. text text text </p>
           </concept>            
        </concept>
     </concept>
     <concept id="5">
        <title>Chapter 2 - Authority</title>
        <p>Time.. authority text text text</p>
        <p>Place.. authority text text text</p>         
        <concept id="6">
           <title>§ 1. Determination</title>
           <p>Time.. Universal Coordinated Time..<b>UTC</b></p>
           <p>Place.. Cartesian Coordinates</p>
        </concept>
        <concept id="7">
           <title>§ 2. Foo</title>
           <p>signatures convey..</p>
           <p>oath is ..</p>
           <p>utterances are ..</p>
        </concept>
     </concept>      
  </concept>
```

Notes:

1. I tried to do it all with axis positioning, I wanted to avoid using the `@id` if I could.
2. OxygenXML brings up the `The descendant axis starting at a text node will never select anything` warning. The web fiddle does not. Curious.

Answer (score 0):

About this remark:

> OxygenXML brings up the The descendant axis starting at a text node will never select anything warning. The web fiddle does not. Curious.

Oxygen validates the XSLT using the Saxon XSLT processor. It means that as long as the XPath in the XSLT stylesheet contains something like this:

> text()[descendant::*]

text nodes have no descendants, so that **descendant::*** selector will not select anything.